# Wear OS TimeText() Exception

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, wear-os

I've just tried to build and run the default Wear OS project for an app with tile and complication, but I get this run-time error in the simulator:

```
Process: au.gondwanasoftware.ontrack, PID: 9869
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method mutableStateOf(J)Landroidx/compose/runtime/MutableLongState; in class Landroidx/compose/runtime/SnapshotLongStateKt; or its super classes (declaration of 'androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotLongStateKt' appears in /data/app/~~q11wAqlBg8mZ6aPx5tjsyw==/au.gondwanasoftware.ontrack-s9r1ombsSKACiWkkVk3gnw==/base.apk)
    at androidx.wear.compose.material.DefaultTimeSourceKt.currentTime(DefaultTimeSource.kt:53)
    at androidx.wear.compose.material.DefaultTimeSource.getCurrentTime(DefaultTimeSource.kt:42)
    at androidx.wear.compose.material.TimeTextKt.TimeText(TimeText.kt:101)
    ...
```

If I comment out `TimeText()`, it runs.

targetSdk is 34.

Something is probably wrong with my configuration. I realise that this probably isn't enough info to diagnose, but I don't know what more is needed. Please let me know!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `build.gradle.kts`, update the version of `androidx.wear.compose` libraries to `1.2.1`:

```
    implementation("androidx.wear.compose:compose-material:1.2.1")
    implementation("androidx.wear.compose:compose-foundation:1.2.1")
```

EDIT:
As per reply in the [bug report](https://issuetracker.google.com/317462916), this fix should be available in Android Studio `Iguana`.

Comment: Very many thanks! I could have sworn I was just doing something daft.