# WearOS compose error: "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method mutableStateOf(J)Landroidx/compose/runtime/MutableLongState"

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, wear-os, mutablestateof

I wanted to start programming a wearOS app, so I just created an new project. But when I started the emulator to check if everything works, the default "hello world" application crashed and threw the following error message:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                    Process: com.example.untistest, PID: 8370
                                                                                                    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method mutableStateOf(J)Landroidx/compose/runtime/MutableLongState; in class Landroidx/compose/runtime/SnapshotLongStateKt; or its super classes (declaration of 'androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotLongStateKt' appears in /data/app/~~PDnTo0MK8A8JpqK1tKoo3Q==/com.example.untistest-8FwhTEebaHIrTkDgGEqZPg==/base.apk)
                                                                                                        at androidx.wear.compose.material.DefaultTimeSourceKt.currentTime(DefaultTimeSource.kt:53)
                                                                                                        at androidx.wear.compose.material.DefaultTimeSource.getCurrentTime(DefaultTimeSource.kt:42)
                                                                                                        at androidx.wear.compose.material.TimeTextKt.TimeText(TimeText.kt:101)
                                                                                                        at com.example.untistest.presentation.MainActivityKt$WearApp$1.invoke(MainActivity.kt:53)
                                                                                                        at com.example.untistest.presentation.MainActivityKt$WearApp$1.invoke(MainActivity.kt:46)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:108)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
                                                                                                        at androidx.wear.compose.material.TextKt.ProvideTextStyle(Text.kt:445)
                                                                                                        at androidx.wear.compose.material.MaterialThemeKt$MaterialTheme$1.invoke(MaterialTheme.kt:84)
                                                                                                        at androidx.wear.compose.material.MaterialThemeKt$MaterialTheme$1.invoke(MaterialTheme.kt:83)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:108)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
                                                                                                        at androidx.wear.compose.material.MaterialThemeKt.MaterialTheme(MaterialTheme.kt:74)
                                                                                                        at com.example.untistest.presentation.theme.ThemeKt.UntisTestTheme(Theme.kt:14)
                                                                                                        at com.example.untistest.presentation.MainActivityKt.WearApp(MainActivity.kt:46)
                                                                                                        at com.example.untistest.presentation.ComposableSingletons$MainActivityKt$lambda-1$1.invoke(MainActivity.kt:39)
                                                                                                        at com.example.untistest.presentation.ComposableSingletons$MainActivityKt$lambda-1$1.invoke(MainActivity.kt:38)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:108)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView.Content(ComposeView.android.kt:428)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView$ensureCompositionCreated$1.invoke(ComposeView.android.kt:252)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView$ensureCompositionCreated$1.invoke(ComposeView.android.kt:251)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:108)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.CompositionLocalsKt.ProvideCommonCompositionLocals(CompositionLocals.kt:195)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt$ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals$3.invoke(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:119)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt$ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals$3.invoke(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:118)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:108)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt.ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:110)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1$2.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:158)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1$2.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:157)
2024-01-03 12:52:54.016  8370-8370  AndroidRuntime          com.example.untistest                E      at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:108)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:157)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:142)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:108)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.ActualJvm_jvmKt.invokeComposable(ActualJvm.jvm.kt:78)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.doCompose(Composer.kt:3340)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.composeContent$runtime_release(Composer.kt:3273)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.composeContent(Composition.kt:588)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.composeInitial$runtime_release(Recomposer.kt:1013)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.setContent(Composition.kt:520)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:142)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:133)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.setOnViewTreeOwnersAvailable(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:1191)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition.setContent(Wrapper.android.kt:133)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition.onStateChanged(Wrapper.android.kt:183)
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry$ObserverWithState.dispatchEvent(LifecycleRegistry.kt:314)
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.addObserver(LifecycleRegistry.kt:192)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:140)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:133)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.onAttachedToWindow(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:1266)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:20516)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3493)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3500)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3500)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3500)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2462)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1997)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8250)
                                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:972)
                                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:796)
                                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:731)
                                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:957)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7660)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

I spent hours trying to find out whats wrong, but I just couldn't find a possible solution for me.I tried different implementations in the build.gradle file, but nothing worked.

Comment: Please try the solution proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77702611/1401164)

Answer (score 0):

I just found It out! Some implementations in the build.gradle fileweren't at the newest version!